# How can i merge two different spannable object of single string

Tags: android, html, spannablestring, spannable, spannablestringbuilder

I have two `spannable` object for same string and both have different styles. I need to merge all `spannable` objects and display all styles into `TextView`.

From one of returning from `Html.fromHtml()` and second return StyleSpan(Bold).

I tried `TextUtils.concate(htmlSpan, boldSpan)` but it displayed same string two times because it append `spannable`, i want to display my all styles into single string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SpannableStringBuilder` but you can create spans inside the `append` method

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
sb.append(String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(stringToConvert));
sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, sb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

And then just set `sb` to your view

```
textView.setText(sb);
```

**EDIT**:

I saw your edited question, Above I **rewrote this code** to get it to apply two spannables on one string. I think you cannot merge different spannable objects on one string. I believe a workaround would be to apply one span, then convert in to string and then apply the second span. This way it will  apply two spans to one string. Or you can manage your bold text type via xml if you always need it in bold

Comment: i already told i don't want to append string, want to merge my two spannable object which applying on same string but both have different style.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my solution, Html.fromHtml() not have spannable type parameter, so firstly i got SpannableStringBuilder from Html.fromHtml() and carry forward it into create Bold StyleSpannable method then set into TextView, and it works awesome.

It retain HTML spannable into bold StyleSpannable method.

Thanks guys for your feed back and response of my answer.

```
SpannableStringBuilder spannable = setTextViewHTML(content);
common.convertBoldString(spannable);

textView.setText(spannable);
```

For the above code content is a variable, which contain words which i like to bold and it also contain HTML tags.

`convertBoldString` is method in my Common methods class which has parameter 
`SpannableStringBuilder` and this object use to set bold StyleSpan.